# Communicate without the intervention of technology

Tags: word-choice, word-request

I'm writing an essay for my English class. It's about technology and what the world was like before many modern inventions.

I want to say *in the past, people used to communicate without the intervention of technology*, is *communicate naturally* a good candidate? I really doubt it though I want to sound brief and natural. What do you suggest?

**Edit:** The comments made me aware that I should be more specific. I mean *the abscence of electronic/electric  devices*. As mentioned in comments communicating through smoke, ink, ravens, and also face-to-face communication. Is there an umbrella term or expression for these? Something like primitive/primary communication maybe!

Thanks

Comment: As long as you define what "natural communication" is. I don't think it would be a well-known concept. BTW, either "how the world was" (no *like*)" or "*what* the world was like".

Comment: We can't rewrite your sentence. If you have a specific question about English usage, though, we want to help! (By the way, since you're talking about the past, you should use the _past tense_ of whatever verb you choose.)

Comment: "In the past, people **communicated** face-to-face without the intervention of technology." Also, remember that electronic communication goes back to at least the 1800s (think of the telegraph, for instance) and that ship-to-ship communication by visual signals or lights preceded that by centuries. Native Americans would notify one another with "smoke signals," a practice that may go back thousands of years. So, the question for you is, "What constitutes 'technology'?"

Comment: @MarkHubbard: ink.

Comment: Yes, the written word! Thank you, @JavaLatte. Manuscripts were a form of communication for thousands of years as well, cave paintings before that, and about 500+ years of printing. You are on shaky ground, Yuri, unless you narrow your definition(s) of technology. :-)

Comment: You could say **communication without high technology**.

Comment: @JavaLatte I'm gonna use that if no better suggestion comes up. Thanks

Comment: Possibly "communication without technology" is enough. You might get away with using "low technology communication".

Comment: I can't bring myself to characterize cuneiform as low technology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. I think *intervention* is a superfluous, unneeded word.
2. I don't like the phrase "used to" in this context; I think it reads awkwardly. I would change it so the simple past (a la Mark Hubbard's comment), or use the word *would*.
3. I agree with the commenters; people have been using technology for a long time. The printing press was a technological marvel in its day.

With those three points in mind, here's my recommended edit:

> *In the past, people would communicate without modern technology.*

Comment: Isn't that rather stating the obvious? If we were pre-modern then we didn't use modern technology?

Comment: @djna - I agree that, by itself, the sentence is stating the obvious. I still think it could work as an introductory remark, though. It's no thesis sentence, but it at least gets the reader thinking.

Comment: Agreed, I'm hard pressed to improve on it without completely rewriting the whole original.

Comment: @J.R. Thanks for your answer though I expected probably a different word or expression because in my native language we use an adjective which its literal translation is _primitive_ it stands against the word _modern_ I thought probably this will stand true in English too.